# How to darken a webpage and show another webpage over it (images attached)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to show a pop-up kind of webpage on another webpage by darkening it as a background as shown in below images. Can you please help me understanding how this can be achieved? Thanks!

Example 1:
[image: The background webpage is darkened]

Comment: Many people below have already answered suggesting that you go get a pre-packaged solution, but if you really just want help understanding the general approach as to how it's done, let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of plugins that help you add this behavior (called light window). If you are using jquery, I can recommend colorbox http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ as I've used it, but there are a bunch of other great plugins. Google 'javascript light window'.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of pre-packaged Javascript plugins that will do this for you - many use jQuery. Try [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) - it will probably do most of what you want out of the box, with little coding.

For a working example that loads another website, see [this ColorBox examples page](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) and click on "Outside Webpage (Iframe)".

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of [these](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) free, already created solutions. It's called Light Box